# How to publish an almost identical version of my android app in a different location

Tags: android

I have released an android app downloadable in the UK, but I wish to release a (very slightly different) version of the app for the U.S. Currently I believe I need to do the following for the new version of the app ...

**1.** Change the 'package' attribute in the manifest file to something different.

**2.** Ensure that on Google Play only the US can download the app.

Is there anything else I am yet to discover I need to do, or any other problems I am yet to consider?

**Edit 19th July 13:19 GMT** - I am currently warming towards using TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso() as an initial country guess, and falling back on the locale if this fails (because of no SIM card). What do people think? Using GPS is also an option though, but is that overkill?

Comment: I've done it before and that looks correct. Only change in code you have to make is the package name.

Comment: Can I ask what the difference is? It might be something you could accomplish using the resource folders or in code, which would simplify things quite a bit.

Comment: Hi kcoppock. A couple of strings which appear on screen change, and a crucial URL the app points to changes. Mmm, you make an interesting point about resource folders, this is maybe something I haven't fully researched or considered? Is there a risk that someone in the UK could change their phone settings to 'US', thus using the wrong version of my app?

Comment: This may be helpful [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Your assumption is correct though, these resources depend on the locale settings of the device. A user could easily switch between the two.

Comment: Hi Matt. How can a user easily change their locale (assuming this is a separate setting to the language)? On my phone I can see how to change the language (Settings -> Language & Keyboard), but I can't see how someone in the US can ensure they are using US locale.

Comment: In the referenced doc it says you can access it via _Settings application (Home > Menu > Settings > Locale & text > Select locale)_. I'm sure it will be different for each phone.

Comment: I've added some further thoughts to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually decided that the best policy was to use TelephonyManager to check the country of the Network.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkCountryCode = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

If that failed, I got the locale.

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

This would happen once at the start of the app. The results of this would then be saved and be configurable in the settings screen.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you're just changing a couple of strings (we'll think of the URL as just a string, too), I would suggest the following:

1. Create the resource directories `res/values` and `res/values-en-rUS`.
2. In each of these, create a [`strings.xml` resource file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)
3. Define your default (UK specific) string values in the `res/values` directory, and your US specific string values  in the `res/values-en-rUS` folder.

Then, to refer to these strings, simply use `@string/my_string_name` when referring to them from an XML document, or `getResources().getString(R.string.my_string_name)` when referring to them from code.

For more details on the types of resource qualifiers, check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), also for the list of qualified country codes you can use, see [this page](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_names_and_code_elements).

I'm sure anyone determined enough could change their region to US -- I'm honestly not sure offhand how the region is determined -- but for all intents and purposes this should do the trick without having to maintain two separate applications. I would just evaluate how critical it is that UK users be unable to access the US specific functions of the application, and with that in mind determine whether it is worth the maintenance of two applications.

**EDIT** Some more additional searching leads me to believe the region is locked into the `build.prop` file, which is not editable outside of rooting your device (i.e. it is not going to happen accidentally). That said, if it's still imperative that they have the correct option, I might suggest a popup dialog only on the first run of the application that confirms the locale with the user, saves it as a SharedPreference, and then choose your Strings programmatically based on that preference. That way you're still only maintaining one application, but you still have the flexibility of handling the two regions.

Comment: Thanks kcoppock. This is great answer that I'm sure will help many people. However, for my needs, US and UK based customers would ALWAYS want to access their respective version of the app. If they don't, the wrong URL within the app would be used, causing confusion. However, as you say, your solution is much more manageable than maintaining two versions of the app, so my decision all depends on how easily users may (confusingly) change their region (something I'm yet to understand).

Comment: On my phone I can change the language easily via 'Settings -> Language & Keyboard'. However, I simply see 'English' as an option, not 'US English' or 'UK English'. If this is the same thing as changing the region though, then your solution is unfortunately not applicable for me. However, if there is some other way to change the region, I'm yet to discover or understand it.

Comment: I'm currently thinking that if the resources files rely on change of language, rather than a change of region, then this is no good, because US residents may speak with a different language. So I need ot detect region. Can this be done? Is my only option to detect the ACTUAL region of the app upon installation, and use that?

Comment: @AndyA The `en` qualifier is the language specifier, the `rUS` *is* a region specifier. I don't believe that simply changing the language will change your region -- I would suggest a quick test application with a simple TextView and some region-specific strings; change your language and see if it changes, but I don't think it will. From some quick searching, I've not been able to discover yet how the region is determined, but the language and region qualifiers are definitely separate.

Comment: Edited in some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The Play Store goes off of two things for who can download and if they can update.  The first is the packagename com.andya.myukapp -> com.andya.myusapp should work, as long as none of your existing customers are expecting to switch freely between the two (assuming it's a paid app)