# How to publish an almost identical version of my iOS app in a different location

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

**My aim and research :** I have released an iOS app downloadable in the UK, but I wish to release a (very slightly different) version of the app for the U.S. Currently I am assuming I need to do the following for the new version of the app ...

1. Change the 'Bundle identifier' value to something different.
2. Ensure that in the App Store only the US can download the app.

**Extra detail :** My app includes a URL to a website. US users always want it to go to the US website. UK users always want it to go to the UK website. This needs to be ensured or the app will not work.

**My question :** Is there anything else I am yet to discover I need to do, or any other problems I am yet to consider?

*Note* : I am also discussing this issue for the android version of my app. This discussion has raised the possibility of maintaining just one app and localising it. *However*, at present I'm doubting whether this is reliable enough for my needs. The decision of whether to maintain 1 app or 2 is likely to affect both android and iOS. [Click here for this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524731/how-to-publish-an-almost-identical-version-of-my-android-app-in-a-different-loca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final decision was to firstly use CTTelephonyNetworkInfo to get the network country ...

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *isoCountryCode = [carrier isoCountryCode];
```

and if that fails, get the locale country ...

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

Then I save the results so it only need to be done once, but enable it to be changed in the Settings screen.

Comment: But +1 to both the other answers for their help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create different apps to sell in different territories. As you stated about. you can create one application and use localization to dynamically change or replace content within the app depending on the localization. This is possible with iOS as well.

Localization is perfectly reliable. It basically just asks the device what default language it is set to, and makes changes accordingly.

Here is a great tutorial on iOS localization from Ray Wenderlich's site.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

However, if you would like to make separate apps, this is acceptable too. You are correct that you would need to create separate bundle ID's. Then, all you need to do is under "Rights and Pricing" in iTunes Connect manually specify what countries you would like the app to be sold in.

As for your primary question of wether or not there is anything else to consider, there really isn't. This process has been made to be very simple, and there aren't any really bad road blocks that you need to worry about running into.

**EDIT:** Different localization options in this context.

1. Using built in iOS localizations
2. Uploading different binaries and localizing in iTunes Connect
3. Using Geolocation services
4. Prompting the user
5. Server-Side location detection and redirection

Comment: Hi MDT. Am I correct in saying that a users region can be changed via 'Settings->General->International->Region Format'? The problem I have is that a US based customer will always want to ensure he is using the  US version of the app.

Comment: Hell, if you don't like localization you could even use location data. Do what MDT suggests.

Comment: @Andy A, even the store-location can be changed, so there is NEVER a guarantee.

Comment: @notreallyJake is right. I'm attaching a link to Apples Core Location class reference. I've never done this, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't make your own localizations based off of what country the user is detected in. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreLocation

Comment: Mmm, I am starting to warm towards this. Location data isn't a viable option I presume though, because if the user goes on holiday to a different location it would use the wrong one. I need to ensure that a US based customer always uses the US version.

Comment: @AndyA That's easy enough to handle, don't use they're location every time. The first time the app is launched get the devices location, set your localization preferences and store the in NSUserDefaults or where ever you see fit.

Comment: So to clarify, I don't think Location data is correct because the user could temporarily be out of the country. And I don't think language is correct, cos a UK English speaker may be in the US (with their phone set to UK English dialect). I need someone who works in the US to always be using the US version. Is localization separate from language?

Comment: Mmmm ... Im just considering MDT's last comment. This could be the best option. But I have to assume they are in the correct country when they download the app. I'm also wondering, when downloading from the App Store though, how does it determine what region you are in?

Comment: I've added some extra detail to my question to clarify the situation ... My app includes a URL to a website. US users always want it to go to the US website. UK users always want it to go to the UK website. This needs to be ensured or the app will not work.

Comment: Even with the details, I'm still fussy on why you are so focused on people not ending up on the wrong website. If you think like this, there is always a reason why you might want to switch (maybe someone moves to the UK?)

Comment: @AndyA Actually another alternative could be to just ask them with a prompt. After they select one you don't ask again but leave an option to change it somewhere in a settings menu... (in case of moving or accidental wrong selection)

Comment: My current conclusion from this discussion is that using the Localizable.strings files is no good, because it seems to relate to language, not location. Are there no language files I can write that relate to region?? If not, as MDT suggests, I'm thinking I would need to detect the region by Location Data upon the first installation, store it in NSUserDefaults, and possible have a setting to change it.

Comment: I'd go with your last option.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to use localization like you got suggested in Android version. I know the user can easily change his/her preferences but also you can strengthen your solution with location and IP-location checks.

And remember, also publishing two versions is not a guarantee. Many people around the world using US iTunes accounts. So it's a great chance to see someone from UK using your US version app.

Comment: Hi Alp. The main question I'm struggling to answer at the moment is whether 'Language' differs from 'Location'. The Localizable.strings files in my app appear to me to relate to language, not region? A UK English speaker in the US would therefore have a problem. Does this mean I cant use the normal localization methods, and instead I need to detect the actual location of the device once its installed, and always use that location?

Comment: Yes, language differs from regional settings. And again yes, British English speaker in US will see the UK version off the mentioned website. But as I stated above, there's not a 100% guaranteed method. In my humble opinion, you must choose the easiest method to implement which is maintaining only one version of the app.

Comment: And yes, you can modify normal localization methods to include a location check. Another option is implementing a selection toggle in app settings. With the help of it, extreme users like British English speaker in US, can select their desired version manually.